# How run to GTK & GLADE based applications in windows?

Tags: windows, gtk, glade

I have made program using gtk and glade in linux. I was just wondering that is there any possible way i can run that program on windows. Lets say I have made my own calculator in linux using gtk & glade and I want it to be run on windows. How can i do this.?

Comment: Yes, there is GTK+ for Windows. You won't find the latest version on the GTK+ homepage, but you can get it through MSYS. The other option would be rewriting to use a different toolkit that supports Windows, if not the Windows API itself.

Comment: To run that program on Windows you shoud proceed as you do with any other C program: you should rebuild it on the target platform. And this involves install or rebuild its dependencies: http://www.gtk.org/download/win32_tutorial.php

Comment: What programming language are you using. For Python I would use pynsist.

Comment: @ntd the bundle on that page is outdated (as I mentioned); the current preferred installation method is via MSYS. I don't know when, if ever, the GTK+ website will be updated, but I believe there's an open issue for it